# Prestashop: get details of a single product using prestashop classes

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm just developing codes for a custom Prestashop module. I can access list of all products in my module using `Product::getProducts(...)` however I don't know how can I access details of specified product having its ID.Can someone tell how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// there is Product object that contains all details of certain product.
// for arguments details see in classes/Product.php constructor method    
$product = new Product($id_of_product_that_you_have, false, $id_lang); 
echo $product->name, $product->description; // etc
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that the second argument is `id_lang`. In your example all language fiels will be arrays

Comment: id_lang is third, but yes, thanks, I really forgot about languages, will change my answer

Comment: @SergiiP another question? how the changes to a specific product can be applied? In other words if `new Product(...)` will bind to an existing product, so how can I can create and submit a new Product in my shop?

Comment: @VSB you should check logic available in classes/ObjectModel.php, you can create instance of existing product with code provided by Sergii make some changes like $product->id_category_default = id_of_some_new_category; and then do `$product->update();`.

You can also create new product by doing

`$product = new Product; 
$product->something = 'something';
...
$product->save();`

You need to check which parameters are required in classes/Product.php

Comment: for `id_lang`  for exemple in ORdetailController.php `$this->context->language->id`

Answer (score 0):

For getting the specific description of the product,
First you have to make a object of product and for that you have to know the id of the product for which you want to get description.

```
$product = new Product($product_id, false, $id_lang); 
$product_description = $product->description;
d($product_description);
```